# Unmarshalling to class using Apache Karavan

Tags: java, apache-camel, unmarshalling

I am trying to unmarshal message from JMS to the class generated by the jaxb plugin nad I am getting this error.

```
ERROR 21048 --- [bbitmq://daniel] or.errorhandler.DefaultErrorHandler : Failed delivery for (MessageId: E7502F289B623F8-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: E7502F289B623F8-0000000000000000).
Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `OrderLineType` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('9')
at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 21, column: 40] (through reference chain: TriggerComponentExecute["executeRequest"]->ExecuteRequest["planItem"]->PlanItemType["orderLine"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

Message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns1:triggerComponentExecute xmlns:tns1="http://ordermanagement/Messages" xmlns:tns3="http://ordermanagement/Types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <tns3:executeRequest>
        <tns3:orchIdentifiers>
                 .
                 .
                 .
        </tns3:orchIdentifiers>
        <tns3:planItem>
            <tns3:orderLine>
                <tns3:orderLineNumber>9</tns3:orderLineNumber>
                <tns3:productID>CFS_139</tns3:productID>
                <tns3:action>PROVIDE</tns3:action>
                <tns3:quantity>1</tns3:quantity>
                <tns3:uom>-</tns3:uom>
                <tns3:subscriberID>1200037</tns3:subscriberID>
                <tns3:eol>false</tns3:eol>
            </tns3:orderLine>
            <tns3:orderLine>
                <tns3:orderLineNumber>10</tns3:orderLineNumber>
                <tns3:productID>CFS_176</tns3:productID>
                <tns3:action>PROVIDE</tns3:action>
                <tns3:quantity>1</tns3:quantity>
                <tns3:uom>-</tns3:uom>
                <tns3:subscriberID>1200037</tns3:subscriberID>
                <tns3:eol>false</tns3:eol>
            </tns3:orderLine>
                 .
                 .
                 .
        </tns3:planItem>
    </tns3:executeRequest>
</tns1:triggerComponentExecute>
```

OrderLineType.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "OrderLineType", namespace = "http://ordermanagement/Types", propOrder = {
    "orderLineNumber",
    "productID",
    "productVersion",
    "action",
    "actionMode",
    "quantity",
    "uom",
    "subscriberID",
    "linkID",
    "inventoryID",
    "eol"
})
public class OrderLineType {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String orderLineNumber;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String productID;
    protected String productVersion;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String action;
    protected String actionMode;
    protected long quantity;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String uom;
    protected String subscriberID;
    protected String linkID;
    protected String inventoryID;
    protected boolean eol;

    public OrderLineType() {
        
    }

    public OrderLineType(String orderLineNumber, String productID, String productVersion, String action,
            String actionMode, long quantity, String uom, String subscriberID, String linkID, String inventoryID,
            boolean eol) {
        this.orderLineNumber = orderLineNumber;
        this.productID = productID;
        this.productVersion = productVersion;
        this.action = action;
        this.actionMode = actionMode;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.uom = uom;
        this.subscriberID = subscriberID;
        this.linkID = linkID;
        this.inventoryID = inventoryID;
        this.eol = eol;
    }

    .
    .
    .
    Getters and Setters
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Yaml file:

```
- route:
    id: route-d289
    from:
      uri: rabbitmq:daniel
      id: from-7b64
      parameters:
        autoDelete: false
        connectionFactory: '#bean:RabbitMQConnectionFactory'
      description: JMSReceiveMessageShared
      steps:
        - log:
            message: ${body}
            id: log-77d5
        - unmarshal:
            id: unmarshal-18d7
            jacksonXml:
              id: jacksonXml-fc7a
              unmarshalType: TriggerComponentExecute
```

If I put only **orderLineNumber** to the constructor with arguments, it works fine but the other elements like productID are empty. Can you help me understand where the problem is?